# Fail to install Anaconda on a mounted folder [Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)]

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am trying to install anaconda on a a mounted network drive which I think is a bit slow, I am running this command:
`./conda.exe constructor --prefix /mnt/nasquatch/data/colabs/anaconda3/ --extract-conda-pkgs`
(I am using this command and not the `./Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh -u -b -p /mnt/nasquatch/data/colabs/anaconda3` to avoid extracting the packages each time)
and get this error:

```bash
./conda.exe constructor --prefix /mnt/nasquatch/data/colabs/anaconda3/ --extract-conda-pkgs
Extracting : regex-2022.3.15-py39h7f8727e_0.conda:   0%|▎                                                                                                                             1/431 [00:04<34:57,  4.88s/it]
Could not remove or rename /mnt/nasquatch/data/colabs/anaconda3/pkgs/libspatialindex-1.9.3-h2531618_0u9jnfyfi/pkg-libspatialindex-1.9.3-h2531618_0.tar.zst.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)

concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 384, in wait_result_broken_or_wakeup
  File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 256, in recv
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
'''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entry_point.py", line 69, in <module>
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 559, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 608, in result_iterator
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 445, in result
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
[69850] Failed to execute script entry_point
'''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entry_point.py", line 69, in <module>
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 559, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 608, in result_iterator
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 445, in result
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
[69655] Failed to execute script entry_point
```

I have permission for the folder, I think it just a bit slow in updating it, from what I see here:
https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/fc92ea3353cce71df24fac31ce333ec9f8cf7ba7/conda/gateways/disk/delete.py#L153
there is a `max_retries` variable, but I do not see that it is used at all. I assume if I would have managed to increase its value it will work, but as I am working with a conda.exe I am not sure how to modify/debug the code.

I also think that maybe mounting the system differently might help.
Any IDEAs?

(I've opened this [ticket](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11977) in conda github, no repones yet)

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
I've found the problem (when trying to move an already installed version [on the same path] to the NAS].
The problem is I was missing the `mfsymlinks` option for the CIFS mount options in `/etc/fstab`

Hope it helps anyone in the future